# Javascript: Sort multi dimensional Array based on first arrays sort results

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array setup similar to this:

```
var ary1 = new Array("d", "a", "b", "c");
var ary2 = new Array("ee", "rr", "yy", "mm");

var mdAry = new Array(ary1, ary2);
```

ary1 and ary2 indexes are info related to each other in the grand scheme of things.

```
d ee
a rr
b yy
c mm
```

I can sort() ary1 and get:

```
a
b
c
d
```

but if I sorted ary2 independently I would get:

```
ee
mm
rr
yy
```

which visually breaks ary1 and ary2 connections when listed out. Can I retrieve ary1's sorted solution and apply that to ary2? I want to get this:

```
a rr
b yy
c mm
d ee
```

If not, could mdAry be sorted so that it applies mdAry[0] sorted solution to the remaining indicies?

Comment: It would probably make more sense to have your data in rows rather than columns. Then you can go back to sorting rows, which is easy.

Comment: Unfortunately I am populating a listbox GUI. Column 1 being the a,b,c,d and column two being the rr,yy,mm,ee content. Once displayed, each listbox item row is info related to one asset.

Comment: Do you need to handle possible duplicate entries? Like [a, a, b, c]?

Comment: I have a function to remove dups already, so I am looking only to get the sorting figured out.

Comment: Just because you're populating a listbox GUI doesn't mean you have to have a multi-dimensional array. You could very easily rewrite your code to use an array of objects, ala `[{col1:'d', col2:'ee'}, {col1:'a', col2:'rr'}, {col1:'b', col2:'mm'}, {col1:'c', col2:'yy'}]`. This is in my mind a superior way to store the data and work with it for many reasons, not the least of which that then you can sort it and the related data stays together! It just doesn't make sense to put data into separate arrays, when elements are supposed to be correlated. Don't use nested arrays to store row-type data!

Comment: For the sake of fun, here's [`array_multisort()`](http://phpjs.org/functions/array_multisort/), inspired by PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could "merge" them into a single object with two properties, sort by the first one, and then separate back in the end (**[see demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/FB6mp/)**):

```
function sortBoth(ary1, ary2) {
    var merged = [];
    for (var i=0; i < ary1.length; i++) merged.push({'ary1': ary1[i], 'ary2': ary2[i]});
    merged.sort(function(o1, o2) { return ((o1.ary1 < o2.ary1) ? -1 : ((o1.ary1 == o2.ary1) ? 0 : 1)); });
    for (var i=0; i < merged.length; i++) { ary1[i] = merged[i].ary1; ary2[i] = merged[i].ary2; }
}

var ary1 = new Array("d", "a", "b", "c");
var ary2 = new Array("ee", "rr", "mm", "yy");

console.log(ary1);
console.log(ary2);

sortBoth(ary1, ary2);

console.log(ary1);
console.log(ary2);
```

Output:

```
[ "d",  "a",  "b",  "c"]
["ee", "rr", "mm", "yy"]
[ "a",  "b",  "c",  "d"]
["rr", "mm", "yy", "ee"]
```

Comment: @DavidTorno It works great, but I just can't resist saying that it's a band-aid on top of a less-than-optimal strategy of data storage.

Answer (score 3):

If your array items are related, then store them together:

```
var arr = [
  {x: 'd', y: 'ee'}, 
  {x: 'a', y: 'rr'}, 
  {x: 'b', y: 'yy'},
  {x: 'c', y: 'mm'}
];

arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  if (a.x != b.x) {
      return a.x < b.x ? -1 : 1;
  }
  return 0;
});
```

Comment: "If you array items are related, then store them together"... Data Structures anyone? +1

Comment: I'd give you +1 only I can't because your sort function tries to do math on string values... ?

Comment: And you made sure it's a stable sort, too. +1.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to transform the data structure to something that can be sorted more easily, and then transform it back after

```
var ary1  = ["d", "a", "b", "c"],
    ary2  = ["ee", "rr", "mm", "yy"]
    mdAry = [ary1, ary2];

// convert to form [[d, ee], [a, rr], ..]
var tmp = mdAry[0].map(function (e, i) {
    return [e, mdAry[1][i]];
});
// sort this
tmp.sort(function (a, b) {return a[0] > b[0];});
// revert to [[a, b, ..], [rr, mm, ..]]
tmp.forEach(function (e, i) {
    mdAry[0][i] = e[0];
    mdAry[1][i] = e[1];
});
// output
mdAry;
// [["a", "b", "c", "d"], ["rr", "mm", "yy", "ee"]]
```

Comment: I think this is the most intuitive solution. It will also be efficient enough assuming displaying in the UI component will be the bottle neck not sorting.

Comment: Another way I thought of is to write your own implementation of a sort algorithm, adapted for doing the same transformations on a second array, but this can get messy in JavaScript. Third idea is similar to first but using indicies instead of `ary2` values for the tmp[i][1], then a loop which modifies these indices in other arrays - the advantage being you can extend it without as much memory usage as a copy of all values.

Comment: Yeah - sorting indices is an option e.g. in python it would look like sorted(range(len(myList)),key=myList.__getitem__)

Answer (score 1):

Just to add yet another method in there, you could get a sort "result" from the first array and apply that to *any* other related list:

```
function getSorter(model) {
    var clone = model.slice(0).sort();
    var sortResult = model.map(function(item) { return clone.indexOf(item); });

    return function(anyOtherArray) {
        result = [];
        sortResult.forEach(function(idx, i) {
            result[idx] = anyOtherArray[i];
        });
        return result;
    }
}
```

Then,

```
var arr = ["d", "a", "b", "c"];
var arr2 = ["ee", "rr", "yy", "mm"];

var preparedSorter = getSorter(arr);
preparedSorter(arr2); 
//=> ["rr", "yy", "mm", "ee"];
```

Or,

```
multidimensional = [arr, arr2];
multidimensional.map(getSorter(arr)); 
// => [["a", "b", "c", "d"], ["rr", "yy", "mm", "ee"]]
```

Comment: This will start to go wrong if you have matching values in an array, i.e. `getSorter(['a', 'b', 'a', 'b'])` will produce a `sortResult` with form `[0, 0, 2, 2]`, so `result` would end up with index `1` as _undefined_ and length `3`.

Comment: You're right that it only works with unique members. I'll see if I can fix it.

Answer (score 0):

In your example the result should be (if I understand correctly)

```
a rr
b mm
c yy
d ee
```

So this one should to the job:

```
Array.prototype.sortRelated = function(related) {
    var clone = this.slice(0), 
        sortedRelated = [];
    clone.sort();

    for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i ++) {
        sortedRelated[clone.indexOf(this[i])] = related[i];
    }

    return sortedRelated;
}

var ary1 = new Array("d", "a", "b", "c");
var ary2 = new Array("ee", "rr", "mm", "yy");

var sorted = ary1.sortRelated(ary2);
```

Working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/cwgN8/